# How to avoid Blur image capture in firebase ML Kit’s Face Detection API

Tags: firebase, face-detection, face-recognition, firebase-mlkit, vision

I am using **firebase ML Kit’s Face Detection API**. And I am using it for detecting a face using front camera of device as shown in the image. [align your face with the outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bALSF.jpg)

So, whenever any face comes into the face overlay it captures an image on successful face detection. On successful face detection I then send the captured image to My own API for further processing. But sometimes it captures a **blur images** which I don’t want. For that purpose, I need to capture best 3 images on successful face detection. So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which camera API you are using? If you are using camera2 API, CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback returns focus and the exposure state through CaptureResult